# how to get All parent categories of a sub category in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a categories schema like

```
const categoriesSchema = new Schema({
_id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
categoryName:{type:String},    
categoryImage:{type:String},    
 parentId:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
  ref:'Categories',default:null},
createdDate:{type:String},
updateDate:{type:String}, });
```

on this schema i have a parent category like shop and its parent id is null because it has no parent. I just create a new category like meat which lies under shop category.i gave the shop id as parent id to it.
for example i have multiple sub category under meat.like chicken,beef etc 
and in chicken category  i have additional sub category like legs,Thai chest. my question is that how can i retrieve all parent categories of legs except the node parent one (shop), like on leg id base i got its parent legs -> chicken -> meat. how can i do in mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the query using `populate()` keyword .

```
Query example : categoriesSchema.find({}).populate('parentId anyOtherFieldOfYourChoice ').exec((err , found)=>{
});
```

Here the `id` stored in `parentID` will look into the `Categories` model and search the appropriate document and shows that whole document in subCatagory data .

Comment: this query gave me only one parent i.e if i choose leg it gave me only his parent chicken. I want all his parents till n-level as i mentioned in my question chicken -> meat etc.. i hope you will understand my question

Answer (score 0):

***You can get tree categories sample:***

```
await Category.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'Categories', // <- schema from which data will be selected (same schema)
      let: { id: '$parentId' }, // <- a variable that will refer to the $parentId field in the current schema
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$parentId', "$$id"] }, parentId: { $ne: null } } }
      ],
      as: 'parent'
    }
  }
])
  .limit(100)
  .skip(10)
  .sort({ categoryName: 'asc', updateDate: -1 })
  .exec((error, categories) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).json(error)
    }
    res.json(categories)
  })
```

**$expr** - will allow you to compare fields in the same document;
**$eq** - allows you to compare two values and returns boolean;
**$parentId** - the name of the field in the current schema;
**$$id** - reference to the variable to be compared with